# Check the series for convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can you help me check the sum for convergence? I have no idea how to deal with this

$S=\frac{2}{1!}-\frac{2^3}{3!}+\frac{2^5}{5!}-\frac{2^7}{7!}+\frac{2^9}{9!}-$...

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition

Comment: Even if you weren't aware of the fact that this is the series expansion of $\sin(2)$, this is an alternating series whose terms tend to zero and so we know the sum to converge.  See [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  series is
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {a_n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n + 1} } \frac{{2^{2n - 1} }}
{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)!}}
$$
You can consider the series
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\left| {a_n } \right| = } \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{2^{2n - 1} }}
{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)!}}} 
$$
You have that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{\left| {a_{n + 1} } \right|}}
{{\left| {a_n } \right|}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{2^{2\left( {n + 1} \right) - 1} }}
{{\left( {2\left( {n + 1} \right) - 1} \right)!}} \cdot \frac{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)!}}
{{2^{2n - 1} }} =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{2^{2n + 1} }}
{{\left( {2n + 1} \right)!}} \cdot \frac{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)!}}
{{2^{2n - 1} }} =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{2^2 \left( {2n - 1} \right)!}}
{{\left( {2n + 1} \right)2n\left( {2n - 1} \right)!}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{2^2 }}
{{\left( {2n + 1} \right)2n}} = 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
Therefore the given series is absolutely convergent and so is convergent also.

Comment: Thanks !!! Nice solution

Comment: Nice that i could help you!

Answer (score 0):

The series  is the Taylor series for the sine function. Therefore, it is equal to $sin(2)$. Since $x=2$.

Comment: I’m not sure whether OP is asking for the sum or just whether it converges.  If it’s only the latter, then it’s probably not a given that the Taylor series converges everywhere.